# When trying to get an instance it returns null

Tags: java, minecraft

I have a Main class where I initialize the instance. I then with the help of a getter want to get that same instance from another class, however, it throws a null pointer exception.

Main class:

```
private static Main instance;

public static Main getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private NPCLib npcLibrary;

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    Main.instance = this;
        
    npcLibrary = new NPCLib(this); 

}

public NPCLib getNPCLib() {
    return npcLibrary;
}
```

Other class:

```
private NPCLib npcLibrary = Main.getInstance().getNPCLib(); //This is null
```

Comment: Is something supposed to be calling `onEnable`? Even if it is, it's unlikely to be called before the field initialisation in your other class.

Comment: `npcLibrary = new NPCLib(this);` is this actually executed successfully? No swallowed exceptions?

Comment: @Fildor yes that is executed successfully.

Comment: @khelwood ok, how would I go about changing it?

Comment: @hampani You could post a [mre], that would help. There's no indication in your code of how or when `onEnable()` is called.

Comment: @khelwood I'd expect `Main.getInstance().getNPCLib();`to throw a NullPointerException, then, am I wrong?

Comment: @Fildor Don't know. No minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Fildor it throws a NullPointerException. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear. I'm new to java

Comment: _"it throws a NullPointerException."_ - yeah then khelwood's comment totally applies. You've got a race condition.

Comment: however, in the docs for the library, I'm trying to use it says to execute it in the onEnable section. https://github.com/JitseB/NPCLib/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md

Comment: I  am tagging your question with `[minecraft]`.  Since that what this appears to be about.  (This may attract the attention of people who understand that platform ... and will help other people to steer clear.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Main class where I initialize the instance.
I dont see the instance initialization.For initializing the instance you need to call constructor for example:

private static Main instance=new Main();